# JSON encode array of objects

Tags: arrays, json, object, socket.io

I have an array of objects like so:

```
[{}, {}, {}]
```

I need to pass this array via Socket.io. Socket.io converts the array into JSON and I keep getting the circular structure to JSON error.

Heres my current code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    num = randRange(0, cards[type].length);
    playerCards.push(cards[type][num]);
}
socket.emit('updateCards', playerCards);
```

Does anyone know a way around this?

Thanks

Comment: The data would be `{id : int, name : string, tag : Object}` These objects are multi-dimensional, containing other objects

Answer (score 0):

You would see the same error if you tried to do the following:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

    num = randRange(0, cards[type].length);
    playerCards.push(cards[type][num]);
    JSON.stringify(cards[type][num]) 
}

//socket.emit('updateCards', playerCards);
```

The tag attribute is likely the culprit.  In order for the JSON serializer to work you cannot have any circular references in the object being serialized.  One option would be to pull out the information needed from the tag object and create a custom object instead.